# Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in post-template.php

Tags: functions

I'm getting this warning with development mode:

> Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in /webDir/project/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 371

In production mode the `<article>` class attribute becomes blank (`class=""`).
This error corresponds to the next function:

```
/**
 * Display the classes for the post div.
 *
 * @since 2.7.0
 *
 * @param string|array $class One or more classes to add to the class list.
 * @param int|WP_Post $post_id Optional. Post ID or post object.
 */
function post_class( $class = '', $post_id = null ) {
    // Separates classes with a single space, collates classes for post DIV
    echo 'class="' . join( ' ', get_post_class( $class, $post_id ) ) . '"';
}
```

After debugging for a while, I've found the issue in the next custom function (functions.php):

```
/* Remove hentry class from "contact" page */

if(! function_exists( 'remove_hentry' )) {
    function remove_hentry( $classes ) {
        $classes[] = customTheme_layout_class();
        if(is_page('contact')) {            
            $classes = array_diff($classes, array("hentry"));

            return $classes;
        }
    }

    add_filter( 'post_class', 'remove_hentry' );
}
```

Removing these lines the warning disappears and the `<article>` classes are shown correctly.
`customTheme_layout_class()` is a theme function with the next code:

```
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
 *  Template functions
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */ 

/*  Layout class
/* ------------------------------------ */
if ( ! function_exists( 'customTheme_layout_class' ) ) {

    function customTheme_layout_class() {
        // Default layout
        $layout = 'col-3cm';
        $default = 'col-3cm';

        // Check for page/post specific layout
        if ( is_page() || is_single() ) {
            // Reset post data
            wp_reset_postdata();
            global $post;
            // Get meta
            $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_layout',true);
            // Get if set and not set to inherit
            if ( isset($meta) && !empty($meta) && $meta != 'inherit' ) { $layout = $meta; }
            // Else check for page-global / single-global
            elseif ( is_single() && ( ot_get_option('layout-single') !='inherit' ) ) $layout = ot_get_option('layout-single',''.$default.'');
            elseif ( is_page() && ( ot_get_option('layout-page') !='inherit' ) ) $layout = ot_get_option('layout-page',''.$default.'');
            // Else get global option
            else $layout = ot_get_option('layout-global',''.$default.'');
        }

        // Set layout based on page
        elseif ( is_home() && ( ot_get_option('layout-home') !='inherit' ) ) $layout = ot_get_option('layout-home',''.$default.'');
        elseif ( is_category() && ( ot_get_option('layout-archive-category') !='inherit' ) ) $layout = ot_get_option('layout-archive-category',''.$default.'');
        elseif ( is_archive() && ( ot_get_option('layout-archive') !='inherit' ) ) $layout = ot_get_option('layout-archive',''.$default.'');
        elseif ( is_search() && ( ot_get_option('layout-search') !='inherit' ) ) $layout = ot_get_option('layout-search',''.$default.'');
        elseif ( is_404() && ( ot_get_option('layout-404') !='inherit' ) ) $layout = ot_get_option('layout-404',''.$default.'');

        // Global option
        else $layout = ot_get_option('layout-global',''.$default.'');

        // Return layout class
        return $layout;
    }

}
```

Any idea of what's the error in my custom function (`remove_hentry`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not returning the default class if you are not viewing the contact page. Try this code once

```
if(! function_exists( 'remove_hentry' )) {
    function remove_hentry( $classes ) {
        $classes[] = customTheme_layout_class();
        if( is_page('contact') ) {            
            $classes = array_diff( $classes, array( "hentry" ) );
        }
        return $classes;
    }

    add_filter( 'post_class', 'remove_hentry' );
}
```